# How do you hide a ListView Item placeholder when it's DataTemplate child is collapsed?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

When the visibility of a `CarViewControl` is set to collapsed, it still shows a placeholder where it used to be (see screenshot below).

Is there any way to completely hide a `ListViewItem` when it is Collapsed?

**XAML Code**

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CarVM.UserCars}" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ctrl:CarViewControl Car="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding HideCar, Converter={ThemeResource InverseVisConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image]

In the image above, there are three `CarViewControls` which are collapsed, followed by one which is not. One is highlighted. I want them to be completely invisible when the content is collapsed.

What I've tried:

- Setting height of the `DataTemplate` control to 0 (just to see if it hides the placeholder which had no effect
- Setting `ShowsScrollingPlaceholders` to `False` based on this documentation: [MSDN ListView Placeholders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn465797.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

**Reason For Collapse Requirement**

Within each CarViewControl, a WebView exists which includes a security token (which maintains that the WebView is logged into a specific web site). If you try to pass the WebView by reference, due to what I can only assume are security measures, you lose that security token and must re-login to the site. That is why adding/removing the control from the `ObservableCollection` will not work in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say your design is flawed, but I can't fix that; so I'll provide a "workaround."

The issue is that your `DataTemplate` is collapsing, which is great, but clearly the container it is in doesn't collapse.  This won't happen inherently because the parent won't inherit from a child.  First realization is every item is wrapped in a `ListViewItem` and you can observe that from setting your `ItemContainerStyle`.  This leaves you with two solutions (workarounds).  You can either set up some triggers on your `ListViewItem` or you can do something easier like I did--and if you don't mind the UI affects.

My full working application is below.  The main point is that you have to edit the layout/behavior of the `ListViewItem`.  In my example, the default values aren't `BorderThickeness` and `Padding` isn't "0, 0, 0, 0"... Setting those to 0 will get hide your items completely.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="CollapsingListViewItemContainers.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollapsingListViewItemContainers"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Disappear Car 3" Click="Button_Click" />
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
                        <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace CollapsingListViewItemContainers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Car> _cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>
                        {
                            new Car("Not yours", "Mine", 1),
                            new Car("Not mine", "Yours", 2),
                            new Car("Not ours", "His", 3),
                            new Car("Not ours", "Hers", 4),
                        };
        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
        {
            get
            {
                return _cars;
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cars[2].IsVisible = !Cars[2].IsVisible;
        }
    }

    public class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isVisible;
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _isVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Car(string name, string title, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Title = title;
            Id = id;
            IsVisible = true;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Let's be honest, the above was a pretty cheap solution and I wasn't satisfied with it after thinking about it for another 3 minutes.  The reason I'm dissatisfied is because you can still select the item if you have access to a keyboard.  In the example above, click the first item, "hide" the item(s), then use your mouse and the `ListView.SelectedItem` will still change.

So below is a quick solution (workaround :D ) to actually remove the item from the list and preventing them from getting focus.  Replace the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` with this one and change the `ActualHeight` trigger value to match the values you're seeing.  This will change based on OS themes I believe--I'll leave it up to you to test.  Lastly, remember the `ListViewItem.DataContext` is going to be that of an item in the `ItemsSource`.  This means the `DataTrigger` bound to `IsVisible` is bound to the `Car.IsVisible` property.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ActualHeight" Value="4">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**Edit 2** (edited before I even posted the first edit.

Screw it, don't bind visibility of your `CarViewControl`; You don't need to.  You solely need to focus on removing the item itself, and once the item is removed, the containing controls will be removed as well (though you should test this yourself and change `IsTabStop` and `IsFocusable` if you can still tab to items in `CarViewControl`).  Also, since using an arbitrary number with the `ActualHeight` binding isn't very safe, just binding straight to the `IsVisible` property (or `HideCar` in your case) and triggering visibility of the `ListViewItem` should be sufficient.

Finally, here is my final XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CollapsingListViewItemContainers.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollapsingListViewItemContainers"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Disappear Car 3" Click="Button_Click" />
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This looks to be a viable solution. I completely forgot about targeting the ListViewItem object via the Setter class. I'll give it a shot once I get home from work this evening. Appreciate the help, mate.

Comment: It ended up being the `MinHeight` property on the `ListViewItem` causing the issue. I simply added `<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>` Appreciate the effort, Mr. Navigator... and for pointing me in the right direction, I shall award you ONE HUNDRED KARMA! Thanks, mate.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: It won't let me award the bounty for another 14 hours. Looks like it'll be tomorrow night, my friend.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of attempting to hide item via the UI, I would remove the item from the View or Collection that the ItemsSource is bound against. It's a cleaner approach, and the UI never has to be concerned about Visibility of an item.

**EDIT 1**

> When a user selects a specific car from the quick select menu, it shows that car and hides the others.

Makes sense; let's call that view "UserCars", and assume the ItemsSource is bound to UserCars.

How about this: change the ItemsSource to be bound to "SelectedCollection". When you want to show UserCars, point SelectedCollection to the UserCars collection.

To limit the set, you'd simply point SelectedCollection to a new SingleCar that you populate with only UserCars.SelectedItem

**XAML:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}">
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private Car _selectedCar;
public Car SelectedCar { 
  get { return _selectedCar; } 
  set { _selectedCar = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCar"); }
}

private ObservableCollection<Car> _selectedCollection = CarVM.UserCars;
private ObservableCollection<Car> SelectedCollection { 
  get { return _selectedCollection; } 
  set { _selectedCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCollection"); }
}

private ObservableCollection<Car> _originalCollectionForReferenceKeepingOnly;

// called via RelayCommand
public void UserJustSelectedACar()
{
    ObservableCollection<Car> singleItemCollection =  new ObservableCollection<Car>();
    singleItemCollection.Add(SelectedCar);
    _originalCollectionForReferenceKeepingOnly = SelectedCollection;
    SelectedCollection = singleItemCollection;
}

public void ReturnToFullUsedCarsList()
{
    SelectedCollection = _originalCollectionForReferenceKeepingOnly;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

It appears that you are trying to make a ListView pretend to be a "Car Details" view by hiding these other items. This is inherently a bad idea; a different UI element bound to the Listview's Selected `Car` Item would make for a better solution. Since the new detail panel would just be looking at an already-generated `Car` instance, you wouldn't incur any data hit. Even if you can make this approach work right now, I'm worried you're going to just cause yourself more grief in the future.

Comment: When a user selects a specific car from the quick select menu, it shows that car and hides the others. If I remove all of the others from the collection then add them back on the fly, they will lose their state and the objects will have to be reinitialized every time the user wants to select an item. I appreciate the thought though.

During the instantiation of each `CarViewControl`, it makes several external api calls to construct the object. If I remove it and add it again, it will have to do it all over again adding extra overhead. Trust me that the best way is to change the visibility.

Comment: I have a private var in here just so that something is hanging onto that crucial 'UsedCars' collection that's expensive to construct.

Comment: Why are you using ListView?  Is it required?  Also, you're doing too much at a time if recreating a view is too expensive.  Show a view which contains few UI elements, when an item is selected, then create your expensive to create UI.  You should be persisting states of objects in your models so that when you create your views they properly reflect changes.

Comment: The control consists of a WebView which is logged into a specific site. If you try to add/remove the control from the collection (or pass the `Control`/`WebView` around), it loses it's state and will no longer be logged into the site. And no, there's no real reason for using a ListView other than the fact that it allows me to bind to a collection and utilize an `Item Template`