# How to remove the placeholder for listview when try to hide selecteditem in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to implement Undo function for my UWP app that has a listview that can be swiped to take action (like left swipe remove, right swipe archive). My xaml summary for the swipe listview is like this

```
<controls:SwipeListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Visibility="{Binding HideForUndo, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationToVisibilityConverter}}">
            SomeContents here...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:SwipeListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And the container style is like this

```
<controls:SwipeListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="controls:SwipeListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</controls:SwipeListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The problem is that after I hide the selected item, there will be some space between the items above and below the selected item. Only when the Undo timer expired and removed the selected item can the space be gone. I can see that the selected item has collapsed and the item below it did move up, but there is just some space.

I found a question that is similar to mine: [How do you hide a ListView Item placeholder when it's DataTemplate child is collapsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768684/how-do-you-hide-a-listview-item-placeholder-when-its-datatemplate-child-is-coll) However it seems doesn't work for me even if I set `MinHeigh`t and `Padding` to `0`.

---

**Edit**:
After testing, I found that this is not related to `ListView` but to the `SwipeListView`.
[image]

The `SwipeListView` added many other controls to it, only the highlighted part will be set to collapsed, other parts still visible.

Comment: What is your `SwipeListViewItem`? Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? For a normal `ListView` and `ListViewItem`, setting `MinHeight` to `0` should be able to work.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Thanks! I tested in the branch that before Swipe action being introduced and it works. But swipeviewlist is really complicated. I think I will dig into swipeviewlist related code for now and I may give you more information.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I updated the question and I'm working on binding the top grid's visibility to the highlighted grid's visibility.

Comment: Are you using this [SwipeListView](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView)? Do you just want to hide the `SwipeListView` when left swipe?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Yes, though we modified it a little bit. I'm trying to hide the selected item when tap a certain button, the visibility of the control inside the contentpresenter or itempresenter can be binded to a property inside the selected item, but seems that the whole grid that contains everything cannot be accessed. Is there anyway to hide the whole grid(I mean the swipelistview selecteditem) when hide the control inside contentpresenter?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I try to do something when the inside grid size has been changed, but it turned out that the height value changes a couple times during initialization and also hiding. I want to bind the outer layer grid's visibility to the visibility inside contentpresenter, but don't know how to bind in this scenario. I'm wondering if you have any idea about this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the details about how you implement the "HideForUndo" function. But if you can get the selected item, I think you can try with [ItemsControl.ContainerFromItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem) method to get the item container which in [SwipeListView](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView) is the `SwipeListViewItem`. After having the `SwipeListViewItem`, you can set `SwipeListViewItem.Visibility` to `Visibility.Collapsed` to hide the whole item.

From the source code of [SwipeListView class](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView/blob/master/Runtime/Universal.UI.Xaml.Controls/SwipeListView.cs), we can find it is derived from [ListView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) and `ListView` inherits from [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), so we can use `ItemsControl.ContainerFromItem` method with `SwipeListView`.

Here using the [Demo](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView/tree/master/Demo) in [SwipeListView](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView) for example:

```
private void SwipeListView_ItemSwipe(object sender, ItemSwipeEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.SwipedItem as EmailObject;
    if (item != null)
    {
        if (e.Direction == SwipeListDirection.Left)
        {
            item.Unread = !item.Unread;
        }
        else
        {
            //(Resources["Emails"] as EmailCollection).Remove(item);
            var swipeListView = sender as SwipeListView;
            var itemContainer = swipeListView?.ContainerFromItem(item) as SwipeListViewItem;
            if (itemContainer != null)
            {
                itemContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the demo, it originally remove the item form items source. I comment out its code and hide the `SwipeListViewItem` instead.

Comment: I was thinking in MVVM and get lost in events notification, it turns out that ContainerFromItem solved every problem...